# Event not published to rabbitmq - using EmitterProcessor

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, project-reactor

I have code for publishing event to rabbitmq:

```
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux
import java.util.function.Supplier

@Component
private class PublishSettlement() : Supplier<Flux<Event>> {
    val processor = EmitterProcessor.create<Event>()

    @EventListener
    fun handle(domainEvent: Event) {
        processor.onNext(domainEvent)
    }

    override fun get(): Flux<Event> = processor
}

data class Event(
    val test: String
)
```

I saw in logs:

```
Jan 15, 2024 @ 00:00:03.047 in: handle(Event(test=31))

Jan 15, 2024 @ 00:00:03.263 in: accept(Event(test=31))

Jan 15, 2024 @ 00:00:03.097 Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory.publisher#404f905:0/SimpleConnection@7cd31487 [delegate=amqp://test@IP:5672/test, localPort= 49118]

Jan 15, 2024 @ 00:00:03.065 Attempting to connect to: [rabbitmqUrlAddress:5672]
```

`accept` is method for handling this event from rabbitmq:

```
@Component
private class CreateStatementFromEvent(
) : Consumer<Event> {
    override fun accept(event: Event) {
        logger.debug { "Create statement from event $event " }
    }
```

But i also see:

```
Jan 15, 2024 @ 00:00:03.046 in: handle(Event(test=30))
```

And this code is not sent to rabbitmq. With `traceId` i don't see here any `rabbitmq` logs, like above one.

I see that method `create`:

```
public static <E> EmitterProcessor<E> create() {
    return create(Queues.SMALL_BUFFER_SIZE, true);
}
```

is `auto-cancel`  Was event here canceled? What happened? Does the narrow time, like milliseconds make here difference ?

```
springBootVersion=2.6.4
springCloudVersion=2021.0.1
```

Comment: Any chance to see a simple project from you to let us to reproduce and play with on our side?

Comment: Right now I can not provide it. I made this question to understand it - maybe this reactive way can loss events ?

Comment: Unfortunately the info you have provided so far is not enough to determine what is going on.